# OpenCV BGR image to 16 bit gray scale

Tags: python, opencv

In OpenCV when I convert JPG image (8 bit per channel) to gray scale, either using `cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` or simply reading it as a grayscale immediately: `cv.imread(path + 'image.JPG', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`, the grayscale image is only an 8 bit image.

**Is there a way of getting a 16 bit gray scale image?**

I know I can square the values of the grayscale image and get 16 bits that way, but I want a true 16 bit of colour information (not 8 bits scaled up).

Comment: Did you try to apply `np.uint16()` on the image?

Comment: @JenilDave, I tried adding `img = np.uint16(img)` before the color conversion, the grayscale output is still only 8 bits of color information.

Comment: Not sure what you are really hoping for because the conversion from BGR to greyscale is only fairly arbitrary/coarse anyway so there's not really much accuracy there to start with, IMHO. Others may have different ideas and I'm happy to be corrected and learn if anyone has a better idea please go for it and say.

Comment: you can scale the image to your needed range (e.g. instead of 0...255 to 65535 by pixel/255*65535) but you wont get any better data information from that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is create your custom function to convert BGR in uint16 to a GRAYSCALE in uint16. Fore example as follows:

```
def bgr2gray(img):
   weights = [0.11, 0.59, 0.3]
   return np.uint16(np.dot(img, weight))
```

Where the weights are the standard weights used to convert from RGB/BGR to grayscale ([https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dip/grayscale_to_rgb_conversion.htm#:~:text=Since%20its%20an%20RGB%20image,Its%20done%20in%20this%20way.&text=If%20you%20have%20an%20color,into%20grayscale%20using%20average%20method.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dip/grayscale_to_rgb_conversion.htm#:%7E:text=Since%20its%20an%20RGB%20image,Its%20done%20in%20this%20way.&text=If%20you%20have%20an%20color,into%20grayscale%20using%20average%20method.)).

Then you would apply this function to the BGR image that you previously converted to uint16. However, this should in general not give you more information than converting the 8-bit BGR image to a 8-bit grayscale image. It would be different if the original BGR image was 16-bit.

To convert from uint8 to uint16, you should use the following formula:

```
img16 = np.uint16(img8)*256
```

Comment: I was trying other ways and I actually ended up doing the same thing as you as was about to post it as an answer :) This method does work though the weights need to be 255 times "heavier" order to scale it up to 16 bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert you 8 bit/pixel gray image to a 16 bits per pixel but you have to note that the 16 bpp image will not transport more information than the original one.

If you want  to keep the original dynamic (0->255) do:

```
img16 = np.uint16(img8)
```

If you want to extend the dynamic (make sense for further processing that require more than 8 bpp prevision ) do:

```
cv.convertScaleAbs(img8,img16,alpha=(65535/255))
```

Comment: I have managed to do something similar (simply by squaring the values). The thing is I kind of “need” the extra information. There is no point (in my case) to go from 8 bit to 16 bit without that extra information. Nonetheless, thank you!

Comment: In that case there is no magic, the information transported in the file (8bpp) is all you have!

Comment: @DatHa Note that you are introducing a non-linearity, or contrast change, if you square the values rather than following Jean-Marc's suggestion which is linear.

Answer (score 0):

Scale the BGR coefficients by 256 before applying them to the image:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Create a small BGR image with unique pixel values

test_img = np.array([[(b, g, r)
                      for b in range(0, 256, 8)
                      for g in range(2, 256, 8)
                      for r in range(4, 256, 8)]], dtype=np.uint8)


coefficients = np.uint16(256 * np.array((.114, .587, .299)))
test_img.dot(coefficients)
```

This does preserve additional information:

```
>>> len(np.unique(cv2.cvtColor(test_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)))
249

>>> len(np.unique(test_img.dot(coefficients)))
7034
```